# match parenthesis with Python

Tags: python, regex

I've been trying to match something like this

```
mystring = "kdjf4kf., kfg. (KFJG)"
regex = r'.+\(\w+\)'
```

But it is not working, it does not find anything. I would like to extrapolate KFJG. How can I do it?

Example:

```
>>> a = "Amazon (AMZN)"
>>> regex = '.?(\w+)'
>>> match = re.match(regex, a)
>>> match.group(0)  
'Amazon'  
>>> match.group(1)  
'mazon'
```

Comment: Please show a complete example of usage and unexpected output. (Finding the solution to a problem is a process.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you forgot to include the match inside a [capturing group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html)

```
>>> re.findall(r'.+\((\w+)\)', mystring)
['KFJG']
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> regex = '.?(\w+)'
```

.? -> this means that there may be a character/number
(\w+) -> this means that capture a character till space occur

`match.group(0)` will return string you want to match ,that's why you see "Amazon"

`match.group(1)` will return first parenthesis grouped content matched in string ,

`'.?(\w+)'` means that matching a string(mazon) which there may be a character(A) before it .

you parenthesis in your code has another meaning in regex, that means Grouping the content for later usage and not serve as a pattern matching here .

what you really want is to capture content inside a parenthesis and parenthesis needs to be escaped in regular via putting a "\"

```
>>> regex = '.*\((\w+)\)'
>>> match = re.match(regex, a)
>>> match.group(0)
'Amazon (AMZN)'
>>> match.group(1)
'AMZN'
```

`'.*\((\w+)\)'` let break it into detail

...`\(_____\)` -> this means match a parenthesis

.....`(___)`   -> this means group inside content for match.group(1)

.......\w+     -> this means matching one or more characters